# SQL: Combinations by Type

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, combinations

I have `set`s organized by `type`.  I want to find all unique combinations of `set`s, taking one `set` from each `type`.  So I start with this:

```
table1:
row_id  type    set
1       a       1
2       a       2
3       a       3
4       b       4
5       b       5
6       c       6
```

and want to get this:

```
table2:
row_id  combo_id    type    set
1       1           a       1
2       1           b       4
3       1           c       6
4       2           a       2
5       2           b       4
6       2           c       6
7       3           a       3
8       3           b       4
9       3           c       6
10      4           a       1
11      4           b       5
12      4           c       6
13      5           a       2
14      5           b       5
15      5           c       6
16      6           a       3
17      6           b       5
18      6           c       6
```

The first idea might be to use `CROSS JOIN` and get something like this:

```
table3:
row_id  combo_id    a_set   b_set   c_set
1       1           1       4       6
2       2           2       4       6
3       3           3       4       6
4       4           1       5       6
5       5           2       5       6
6       6           3       5       6
```

However, my real data has thousands of `type`s with no upper bound on that number, so I think the setup in `table2` is necessary.

I see there are many Stack Overflow questions about SQL combinations.  However, none that I found addressed sorting by `type`, let alone an unbounded number of `type`s.

I'm using PLSQL Developer with Oracle 10g.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have thousands of types, there is no way (in this universe at least) that you can list all of them out -- except in the trivial case where almost all only have one row.  Can you better describe your real problem?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, this is my real problem, just with many fewer `type`s.  I do have thousands of `type`s, but they all have only a few rows apiece.

Comment: . . If you had 1000 types with 2 rows each, you would have 2^1000 different combinations.  The number of atoms in the universe is estimated around 2^272.  The number of milliseconds since the big bang is estimated more like 2^68 milliseconds.  Hence my comment about the universe and what your actual problem might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to arrive at your table2 representation would be to use an Up-and-Down hierarchical query:

```
with table1(row_id, type, val) as (
select 1, 'a', 1 from dual union all
select 2, 'a', 2 from dual union all
select 3, 'a', 3 from dual union all
select 4, 'b', 4 from dual union all
select 5, 'b', 5 from dual union all
select 6, 'c', 6 from dual
), t2 as (
select row_id
     , type
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY type desc) type_id
     , val
  from table1
), Up as (
select row_number() over (partition by CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF
                              order by SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(row_id, ',')) combo_id
     , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(row_id, ',') path_id
     , prior SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(row_id, ',') parent_path_id
     , t2.* 
     , CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF leaf
  from t2
 connect by type_id = prior type_id+1
 start with type_id = 1
), Down as (
select row_number() over (order by CONNECT_BY_ROOT combo_id, type) row_id
     , CONNECT_BY_ROOT combo_id combo_id
     , type
     , val
  from Up
  connect by path_id = prior parent_path_id
  start with leaf = 1
)
select * from Down;
```

In this solution subquery `t2` adds a sequential id for each unique `type` I've ordered them in reverse order so that the first traversal will end up with `type` 'a' as the leaf nodes.

In the first tree traversal (subquery `Up`) I add a unique combo code to all the leaf records for grouping purposes and add the `path_id` and `parent_path_id` columns  used in the next tree traversal.  This is also the stage where all the new rows are generated.

In the second tree traversal (subquery `Down`) I start at the leaf nodes from the `Up` traversal and climb back down to the root keeping the root (leaf?) `combo_id` generated in the prior traversal.  No additional rows are generated in this stage since it's a straight shot from the leaf back to the root of the tree.

The final result:

```
  ROW_ID   COMBO_ID T        VAL
-------- ---------- - ----------
       1          1 a          1
       2          1 b          4
       3          1 c          6
       4          2 a          2
       5          2 b          4
       6          2 c          6
       7          3 a          3
       8          3 b          4
       9          3 c          6
      10          4 a          1
      11          4 b          5
      12          4 c          6
      13          5 a          2
      14          5 b          5
      15          5 c          6
      16          6 a          3
      17          6 b          5
      18          6 c          6

 18 rows selected
```

If you want your Table3 representation you can change the `select * from Down` to this:

```
select row_number() over (order by combo_id) row_id
     , pvt.*
  from (select combo_id, type, val from Down)
 pivot (max(val) "SET"
   for (type) in ('a' A
                 ,'b' B
                 ,'c' C)) pvt;
```

Yielding the following result:

```
    ROW_ID   COMBO_ID      A_SET      B_SET      C_SET
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          4          6
         2          2          2          4          6
         3          3          3          4          6
         4          4          1          5          6
         5          5          2          5          6
         6          6          3          5          6
```

Comment: Interesting!  Very old problem but great to see an answer

Comment: @esa606 Thanks it was a nice excercise. I've added a pivot to get the final table3 layout from your original question, and fixed the ordering of Combo_ID to get the exact same output you had :)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81ad5/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( "rowid", "type", "set" ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'a', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'a', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'a', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'b', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'b', 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'c', 6 FROM DUAL
//
CREATE TYPE combo_sets AS OBJECT(
  "type" CHAR(1),
  idx    NUMBER(5,0),
  sets   SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
);
//
CREATE TYPE t_combo_sets AS TABLE OF combo_sets;
//
CREATE TYPE combo AS OBJECT(
  "rowid"    NUMBER(8,0),
  "comboid"  NUMBER(8,0),
  "type"     CHAR(1),
  "set"      NUMBER(5,0)
);
//
CREATE TYPE t_combos AS TABLE of combo;
//
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_combos
RETURN t_combos PIPELINED
AS
  v_combo_sets t_combo_sets;
  i            NUMBER(5,0);
  r            NUMBER(5,0) := 1;
  c            NUMBER(5,0) := 1;
BEGIN
  SELECT combo_sets( 
           "type",
           1,
           CAST( COLLECT( "set" ORDER BY "set" ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST )
         )
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_combo_sets
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY "type";

  i := 1;
  WHILE i <= v_combo_sets.COUNT LOOP
    FOR j IN 1 .. v_combo_sets.COUNT LOOP
      PIPE ROW(
        combo(
          r,
          c,
          v_combo_sets(j)."type",
          v_combo_sets(j).sets( v_combo_sets(j).idx )
        )
      );
      r := r + 1;
    END LOOP;
    c := c + 1;

    i := 1;
    WHILE i <= v_combo_sets.COUNT AND v_combo_sets(i).idx = v_combo_sets(i).sets.COUNT LOOP    
      v_combo_sets(i).idx := 1;
      i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    IF i <= v_combo_sets.COUNT THEN
      v_combo_sets(i).idx := v_combo_sets(i).idx + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
//
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( get_combos )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81ad5/1/0)**:

```
| rowid | comboid | type | set |
|-------|---------|------|-----|
|     1 |       1 |    a |   1 |
|     2 |       1 |    b |   4 |
|     3 |       1 |    c |   6 |
|     4 |       2 |    a |   2 |
|     5 |       2 |    b |   4 |
|     6 |       2 |    c |   6 |
|     7 |       3 |    a |   3 |
|     8 |       3 |    b |   4 |
|     9 |       3 |    c |   6 |
|    10 |       4 |    a |   1 |
|    11 |       4 |    b |   5 |
|    12 |       4 |    c |   6 |
|    13 |       5 |    a |   2 |
|    14 |       5 |    b |   5 |
|    15 |       5 |    c |   6 |
|    16 |       6 |    a |   3 |
|    17 |       6 |    b |   5 |
|    18 |       6 |    c |   6 |
```